# Solving a 2-Variable function to only 1 of the variable doesnt work on arrays

Tags: python, function, scipy, solver, equation-solving

I have found from StackOverflow how to solve a fucntion with two variables giving the one as constant/known.

This is the part of the code:

```
def R(gg,a):
    return a-r0*g0**(1/2)*D(gg)/gg**(1/2)
def G(r):
    partial_func = functools.partial(R, a=r)
    return fsolve(partial_func,10,xtol=10**-1)
```

and it works, since  for the first 2 prints, I get the same value

```
f=([10,15])
print(G(10))
print(G(f[0]))
print(G(f))
```

but when giving the full array it has the following error:

`The array returned by a function changed size between calls`

Comment: Are you aware that `f` is a tuple of a list?? I think you mean `f=[10, 15]`..right?

Comment: @Anwarvic It's actually a list since a one element tuple is `([10,15],)` but the brackets are not necessary.

Comment: `f` is not a tuple of a list. it would be if you would write `f=([10,15], )`

Comment: Yup, you are right ;)

Comment: @billy You should attach the returned values and definitions for all variables to make it easier to help

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve), `fsolve` expects `partial_func` to take a vector as input and return a vector of the same length. It looks like `partial_func` is taking a scalar but returning a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to find the roots of `R` for different values included in `f`.

The problem is that `partial_func` has an single value as starting estimate and wants to return an array of the same length as `a` (in your case 2 values).

In other words, there is not a single value root to your problem. For example the root for `f[0]=10` is probably different from the root for `f[1]=15`. The solution should be an array of two values in this case.

To fix this, you need to give an array for the `x0` (starting estimate) parameter of `fsolve`.

```
def G(r):
    partial_func = functools.partial(R, a=r)
    return fsolve(partial_func,[10,10],xtol=10**-1)
```

So that for each values in `a` there is a initializer for `gg` and the solution is a vector of the same length as `f`.

Comment: Wait, actually  I have a problem. When I  give G(f) as a result I get ([f[0],f[1]]) and not G(f[0]),G(f[1]). What's to blame here? :(

Comment: I don't understand. See [this snippet](https://codepad.co/snippet/1IkWsM9g) which returns the roots of `R` for the values present in `f`. Let me know.

Comment: I get `f=[10 15 17] G(f[0])= [30.73218835] G(f[1])=[39.49923357] G(f[2])=[41.79696086]` and `G(f)=[30.73259241 39.66454009 42.16416723]~=[G(f[0], G(f[1], G(f[2])]`

Comment: Any reason why they are not the same values?

Comment: There is no guarantee that you will have the exact same values. This is a numerical approach where "The calculation will terminate if the relative error between two consecutive iterates is at most xtol." If you refine `xtol` the algorithm will run longer and give you more precise and similar answers.

Comment: Just a last code to see that there is a problem. If you run  [this](https://pastebin.com/VbcmPHM8) you will see that there is a huge difference. I mean it can't be the tolerance. :(  :(

Comment: There is indeed a huge difference because the `e00` function is very flat and close to zero. That's the limit of a numerical approach.

Comment: BTW, carefully choosing the starting estimate is very important. You will see that there is an error message in the result of your last example if you pass `full_output=True`

Answer (score 1):

So reading this w/o knowing all parameters used in the function i would say that in case of `print(G(f))` you provide a scalar and return an array, which does not work.

Try calling your function with `a=f` and look at the returned value.

The docs state:

`fsolve: func: A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument, and returns a value of the same length`